# Software to check for missing brackets/tags/html?

Tags: html, web-development

I would like a software that could check for missing HTML elements tags/brackets/html/ for me, in the entire file.

I don't have preference for paid or free. Just an IDE or Text Editor/other that checks for me, instead of keep looking for it manually.

Answer (score 1):

## WebStorm

The JetBrains company provides some of the most powerful programming tools available, including their IntelliJ IDEA tool for Java programmers.

They have used their core technology to produce [*WebStorm*](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) expressly for web work, editing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Enjoy code completion, powerful navigation features, on-the-fly error detection, and refactoring.